# Unresolved reference error JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8 android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

In android studio project structure it shows unresolved reference error.

```
sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
```

If I changed above lines to the following, the error doesn't appear.

```
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
targetCompatibility = '1.8'
```

Can anyone please tell me why the error occurs?

[SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNDEv.jpg)

Comment: Have you migrated the existing project to AndroidX

Comment: Hi Shalu T D, thanks for the reply. I just created new project with androidX.

Comment: It may happen when you updated the existing project with AndroidX

Comment: Ok thanks. But what is the reason, why the error occurs?

Comment: JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8 enum is unrecognised in android studio project structure